# Morphing unequal path svg text

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, snap.svg

So I have a problem wherein I morph an SVG text to another text by using path `d` but it seems like a MorphSVG can't make an svg that doesn't equal to the different class...

So for example let say `EMAIL` for svg path `d` which will be a class `start` and for the other one which has more than `start` and that is class `exit` and for that let say `JUMBORAT` for svg path `d` now the thing is that since **JUMBORAT** has more path `d` than **EMAIL**.. then svg path animation doesn't match with the path of more than that class and giving that when I morph it it will comes up with **JUMBO**. I'm using a snap svg..and here's the example that you can see for yourself.

https://codepen.io/myth-vince/pen/qBoOLJG

I almost got it but also wrong with the wrong matching of length of path `class` `d`. If anyone can help me through this thanks a lot.

Comment: There's normally no simple way to morph unequal path points if I'm understanding the question right. One solution is to create the same amount of points by interspersing new inbetween points. Eg if you need 3 extra points, find the largest 3 lengths and insert 3 points halfway along the lines. (You may find a few algorithms to do similar out there in the wild).

Comment: where can I do that?

Comment: how about hide an add an another path but it should be invisible and then after morphing it will become also equal? does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, thats similar to what I was suggesting I think, just it's precalculated in your suggestion, which is fine if it's known in advance.